# What should I take Intel PAA / x86_64 GNU / Linux

Tags: drivers, video, intel

### I have an Intel graphics card

on

3.5.0-36-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 20 18:21:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
 lspci-nnk | grep-i VGA-A2

 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c: 1858]
 Kernel driver in use: i915
```

1. What a PAA I need to take so that I have full power so I can play with Steam?

   Will Steam install to Softwarecenter

   > Steam needs to install these additional packages:
   >   libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-quantal:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-quantal:i386, libc6:i386

   ```
   /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p  

    Intel Open Source Technology Center
    OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel (R) Sandy Bridge Mobile
    OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 9.0.3

    Not software rendered: yes
    Not blacklisted: yes
    GLX fbconfig yes
    GLX texture from pixmap: yes
    GL npot or rect textures: yes
    GL vertex program: yes
    GL fragment program: yes
    GL vertex buffer object: yes
    GL framebuffer object: yes
    GL version is 1.4 +: yes

    Unity 3D supported: yes
   ```
2. And what `/` entries Should Be in my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

   ```
   Section "Screen"
   Section "Device"
   ```
3. `cat /proc/cmdline`

   ```
   BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-36-generic root=UUID=d49f068f-52ac-47ed-8a03-71b7a69884f6 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
   ```
4. `dmesg | grep i915`

   ```
   [    1.155970] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
   [    1.191712] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
   [    1.870345] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
   [ 5385.318716] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
   [18434.366480] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
   [23459.306806] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
   [24639.875228] i915 0000:00:02.0: setting latency timer to 64
   ```
5. `glxgears` screenshot: http://screencloud.net/v/9FM4.

   Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
   approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.

   ```
   296 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.110 FPS
   300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.912 FPS
   300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.902 FPS
   300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.900 FPS
   300 frames in 5.0 seconds = 59.904 FPS
   ```
6. `xrandr --prop`.

> > Blockquote Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192 LVDS1 connected 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x
> >     axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm    EDID:       00ffffffffffff0030e4840300000000
> >           00160104902213780a01a59c595a9b26        18505400000001010101010101010101
> >           010101010101d81d56f4500016302430        350058c21000001be51356f450001630
> >           2430350058c21000001b000000000000        00000000000000000000000000000002
> >           000c47ff0a3c6412222964000000007f    BACKLIGHT: 6 (0x00000006)   range: 
> >     (0,10)    Backlight: 6 (0x00000006)   range:  (0,10)  scaling mode:   Full
> >     aspect        supported: None         Full         Center       Full aspect
> >     1366x768       60.1*+   40.0      1360x768       59.8     60.0
> >     1024x768       60.0      800x600        60.3     56.2      640x480
> >     59.9   VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
> >       Broadcast RGB:  Full        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
> >       audio:  auto        supported: force-dvi    off          auto         on
> >     DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)   Broadcast
> >     RGB:  Full        supported: Full         Limited 16:2    audio:  auto
> >           supported: force-dvi    off          auto         on

7.) `/etc/default/grub`

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

Currently have the PAA
`# ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates && sudo apt-get update -y`

### I have the following problem

What should be in the `xorg.conf`?
What should be in the `/ etc / default / grub`?

at the moment it shows me under this Serious Sam 3 BFE http://screencloud.net/v/EX1g 
and is Non Playable and jerky

```
sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
       Produkt: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       Hersteller: Intel Corporation
       Physische ID: 2
       Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
       Version: 09
       Breite: 64 bits
       Takt: 33MHz
       Fähigkeiten: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       Konfiguration: driver=i915 latency=0
       Ressourcen: irq:42 memory:c2000000-c23fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(Größe=64)
```

> ```
> hwinfo --gfxcard
> > hal.1: read hal dataprocess 12471: arguments to dbus_move_error() were incorrect, assertion "(dest) == NULL ||
> ```
>
> !dbus_error_is_set ((dest))" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-errors.c
>   line 282.
>       This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
>       libhal.c 3483 : Error unsubscribing to signals, error=The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files
>       08: PCI 02.0: 0300 VGA compatible controller (VGA)
>         [Created at pci.318]
>         Unique ID: _Znp.nDJOnrrEzD7
>         SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0
>         SysFS BusID: 0000:00:02.0
>         Hardware Class: graphics card
>         Model: "Intel VGA compatible controller"
>         Vendor: pci 0x8086 "Intel Corporation"
>         Device: pci 0x0116 
>         SubVendor: pci 0x103c "Hewlett-Packard Company"
>         SubDevice: pci 0x1858 
>         Revision: 0x09
>         Driver: "i915"
>         Driver Modules: "drm"
>         Memory Range: 0xc2000000-0xc23fffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
>         Memory Range: 0xb0000000-0xbfffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
>         I/O Ports: 0x4000-0x403f (rw)
>         IRQ: 42 (100414 events)
>         Module Alias: "pci:v00008086d00000116sv0000103Csd00001858bc03sc00i00"
>         Driver Info #0:
>           Driver Status: i915 is active
>           Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe i915"
>         Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
>
> `Primary display adapter: #8`

Answer (score 0):

*Intel HD 2000 Graphics driver* is open source, and you don't need to install anything.

But possible to improve performance, leave *xorg* Settings automatic.

Use the latest version of *Linux* kernel and *mesa*

And keep the CPU GOVERNOR "performance" (You can do that in Ubuntu by installing *indicator-cpufreq* and run it from terminal: *indicator-cpufreq* , You will see the program icon in the panel)